# Would a western video game identification question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, story-identification

There's a video game that takes place in a town in the wild-west that I remember vividly, but I can't find any pics or proof online to be able to post in the Arqade community. Reading the description for identification, I'm not sure if it falls under the umbrella sci-fi/fantasy. Would this be an okay question to pose? If not, is there any other place I could -- or am I screwed?

Answer (score 16):

Same as always (though I don't remember the exact meta at the time).

- If you're positive it has sci-fi/fantasy elements, and can provide them, sure, it's on topic;
- If you can't remember its SFF parts but are dead positive it had some, then it's on-topic (although you'll likely get close votes), per the votes on the answers to [Is a story identification question on-topic if it doesn't include genre defining elements?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12170/);
- If you're not sure it has SFF elements and is more likely a "regular" kind of western game (which is apparently your case here)... Then it's probably off-topic for here, and as you don't have an artifact (screenshot, soundtrack etc), you can't post on Arqade. [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) is fine, as are [r/tipofmytongue](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/) on Reddit, and probably a couple other game-ID sites.

---

As a side note, for such questions, it may be clearer to write the question as you would ask it and include it in the Meta question. That makes its scope easier to figure, kind of like [site-recommendation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) on main Meta should include the question at stake.

Comment: To give concrete examples, [*Hard West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_West) would be on-topic for this site, but [*Call of Juarez*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Juarez_(video_game)) would not.